# In-browser Applet automation

Tags: java, applet, automation

I am trying to automate in-browser applet.  Currently I am automating using reflection and accessibility, but for in-browser applets I am not finding any approach.

Can anyone provide an approach or sample code to do this?

Your views on the problem are appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Extend the applet to get control of it.  Once it is extended, it is possible to gain direct access to the controls.  Add whatever functionality you need in order to automate it.

2 possibilities are:

1. Create sockets to have the applet controlled by a remote application.
2. Provide public methods that can be called using JavaScript.

Of course, you will need to host the extended applet in your own HTML.

Comment: That can be a third party applet.

Comment: Yes it can. (I don't know why you bothered to tell me something I already know, but ..thanks(?)).

Comment: Can you plz elaborate more. That will be really helpful.

Comment: Can you please spell words like 'please' correctly?  This is not a text message.  As to me elaborating: ask a specific question or questions.

Comment: Let me explain you the scenario in detail, I am running a third party applet in a browser. I want to enter some values in text fields and click on say, "OK" button. After click on OK button I want to retrieve value from some text field. How can I do this?

Comment: See the update.  Note that none of this is 'easy', but that is applets for you.  ;)

Comment: Can you explain in more detail how I would extend a pre-existing Java applet? (Or provide references for how to extend it)

Comment: @StevenVascellaro Too much detail for a comment. Ask a new question.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I wouldn’t even know where to start with the question, as I don’t know what extending a Java applet would do

Comment: @StevenVascellaro *"I wouldn’t even know where to start with the question.."* Work it out, if you want my help. Note that SO is a Q&A Site, not a tutoring service.